# ディレクトリを作るプログラムを書いたのですが、、

Tags: c, ubuntu

ディレクトリを作成するプログラムを書いたのですが実行してもディレクトリができません
何が間違っていてどんなところに原因があるのかわかりません。。

OS は ubuntu 15.04 です。

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    system("cd\n");
    system("mkdir n3\n");
    system("cd n3\n");
    system("mkdir down\n");
｝
```

Comment: OSは何ですか？最初の引数なしの`cd`はどのような挙動を期待していますか？

Comment: ~/ へ移動してもらうことを期待しています。　ubuntu 15.04  の64ビットです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`system` 関数はコマンドプロセッサ（シェル）を呼び出して指定したコマンドを実行します。
呼び出したシェルは別プロセスなので、`main`に帰ってきた時には`cd`のようなコマンドは現在のワーキングディレクトリに反映されません。
なので、このような別々の`system`関数の呼び出しは期待したように動作しません。

例えば、一行で、
`system("cd && mkdir n3 && cd n3 && mkdir down");`のように書きます。

Answer (score 3):

`cd`でのワーキングディレクトリの変更が次の`system`のワーキングディレクトリには影響しないのが原因なので、一連のコマンドを１行につなげてもOKですが、`cd`を使わずに一つの`mkdir`コマンドだけで同じことができます。

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    system("mkdir -p ~/n3/down");
}
```